# Homework Assistance, program not returning a value

Tags: c++

Im having trouble with the function taylor2 not returning a value if i input anything over 2. If I enter 0-2 it outputs the correct value but anything over 2 and I just get a flashing underscore with no data returned.

```
void taylor2(double x)
 {
     double total = 1;
     int i = 0;
     int count = 1;
     double temp = 1;

     do
     {

     {
         if (i % 2 == 1)
         {
             temp = (pow(x, i * 2 + 2) / factorial(i * 2 + 2));
             total += temp;
         }
         else {
             temp = (pow(x, i * 2 + 2) / factorial(i * 2 + 2));
             total -= temp;
         }
     }

     count++;
     i++;


     } while (fabs(temp) >= .0001);

     cout << "The last recoreded temporary value was: "<<temp << endl;
     cout << "The computed value for cosine is :  "<< total << endl;
     cout << "It took " <<count << " values to calculate the value of the function to .0001 places"<< endl;
     cout << endl; 
 }
```

Comment: `void` means your function cannot return a value.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with `factorial()`, show us it's code

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `factorial` is returning an `int`. If `int` is 32 bit (very common), then `factorial` will overflow once the argument reaches 13 (`i = 5` in your case). Signed integer overflow is *undefined behaviour* in C++.

You could use a `std::uint64_t` (an unsigned 64 bit integer). This will allow you to evaluate a few larger factorials.

For more reference, see [Calculating large factorials in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098319/calculating-large-factorials-in-c)

Better still, use a *recurrence* relation between your Taylor terms.