# Output a huge number with 200,000 digits

Tags: c++

I am trying to output a number with 200,000 digits and not sure how I can store it? The task is to compute the 1 millionth fibonnacci number, so it would be a formula outputting 200,000+ digits. In other words, saving the output somehow of the calculation so that I can then output.

```
size_t longnumber; // number with 200,000 digits
cout << longnumber;
```

Comment: with 200,000 digits, you should store it as string

Comment: are you asking how to output it or how to store it?

Comment: i just need to output the number

Comment: You will not be able to store it in *standard* integral types. On most system the largest one is `uint64_t` which can represent numbers up to 19 decimal digits, some offer `uint128_t` (up to 38 decimal digits). But here, you will have to use a multi-precision library (either roll your own or google for it), or simply store it as a string.

Comment: Search for `[c++] large number` to get an idea of how others work with such problems.

Comment: many of the examples I've found are people looking for 100 digits, or 10,000 digits, haven't found anything on like 200,000 scale

Comment: I will try storing it as a string first and then the big number libraries

Comment: Why do the other solutions not work for you? What is the exact issue?

Comment: I'm trying what people have commented is what I meant. The first person commented storing it as a string and then someone said to use precision libraries, so thats what I meant by my 2nd to last comment

Comment: A *bignum* library will provide functions to perform calculations. If you store the number as a string you'll have to implement the mathematical operations yourself.

Comment: The only reason for giving anyone this exercise is when they should implement addition of huge numbers themselves. I would personally use `std::vector`, not strings. (There are countless examples both online and on this site, and 10,000 and 200,000 are on the same scale.)

Comment: The string method didn't work, I am trying vectors now before I go into the bignum libraries

Comment: @johanndewey The "string method" means you have to implement the addition yourself by using "schoolbook" math.  Did you do that?  That means you have to implement addition, carry, etc.  So I don't see how using a vector will remove this requirement.

Comment: @johanndewey If the string method didn't work, you implemented it wrong. (And if the purpose of this exercise is implementing the addition yourself, using a library means that you fail.)

Comment: Please show your attempt with the "string method" and the reasons it "didn't work". As it's now, your question is too broad and risks to be closed.

Comment: @johanndewey FYI, Using [boost multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html), this [program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80cf9baccf137719) took around 39 seconds to complete, running release mode, Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. That's a great result. My answer below needs an hour. But completely non-optimized. Your result is a challenge. I will play with it a little bit further . . .

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Can you confirm 39 seconds to run your program for 1'000'000 ? Getting the 208988 digit result? I am really wondering how boost could outperform my second approach by a factor of 10. I elimiated all copy activities, but still need 404 seconds. Maybe I need to reduce the indirections and use more pointers. Strange . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny It took 39 seconds on an Intel I7 laptop.  Why not try it yourself?  The second thing is that the components in boost have been fine-tuned over the years.  The multiprecision library isn't some project that took an hour or two to put together -- the full source code is available to you to take a look at it.  And yes, the resulting number of digits is 208988.

Comment: Also, are you running an unoptimized, debug version, or an optimized build?  If it is an unoptimized build, then the timings are meaningless.

Comment: @ArminMontigny If I may, your approach stores the bignums into vectors of `char`s representing a single decimal digit. I seem to recall that the gmp approach is to store "digits" as big as 32-bit (or 64-bit) words (binary, I think, but you can try with the biggest storable decimal number).

Comment: Have a look at [Calculate the factorial of an arbitrarily large number, showing all the digits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1966077/5987).  I'd expect Fibonacci to be easier than Factorial.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to include both calculation of this number and the storing and printing it.

I will suggest using vector to store the number and to grow it as you keep on adding your fibonacci list

for e.g
1 1 2 3 5 8 13

```
std::vector<int> res;

std::vector<int> prev;

res[0]=1         prev[0]=0
res[0]=1         prev[0]=1 
res[0]=2
res[0]=3
res[0]=5
res[0]=8
res[0]=1 res[1]=3    prev[0]=8
```

Code : it's just  minimum example for POC

```
std:vector<int> prev{0};
std:vector<int> res{1}

add(){
       for(auto a=res.size();a>=0;--a){
          for(auto b=prev.size();b>=0;--b){
              temp=res[a]+prev[b];
               if(temp > 9){
               // take carry and redo the add 
 } 

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the standard approach for calculating Fibonacci numbers like in the following simple algorithm.

```
constexpr unsigned long long getFibonacciNumber(size_t index) noexcept {
    unsigned long long f1{ 0ull }, f2{ 1ull }, f3{};
    while (index--) { f3 = f2 + f1; f1 = f2; f2 = f3; }
    return f2;
}
```

But, even using the 64 bit data type `unsigned long long` it will overflow after the 93rd Fibonacci number.

So, what we need is some "very big" data type. And here I propose a `std::vector` of digits. And as digit we will use an `unsigned char`.

For the following we will talk about "Digit" and "Digits" meaning an `unsigned char` and a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

For adding 2 Digits, we will use the method that we learned in school, when we were 7 years old. We add all single digits, and if there is an overflow over 10, we use it as "carry over" and add it the next time. That is rather simple.

Then we build an `operator +` for 2 "Digits", taking a little bit care about different number of elements in Digits and employ the simple "add" algorithm.

The code will then look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

using Digit = unsigned char;
using Digits = std::vector<Digit>;

// Unoptimzed adder for vector of Digits
Digits operator + (const Digits& d1, const Digits& d2) {

    // This will produce many not needed leading 0's
    const size_t ResultSize = std::max(d1.size(), d2.size()) + 1;

    // The result of the additions
    Digits result(ResultSize, 0);

    // The carry over from a addition of 2 digits
    unsigned char carry = 0;

    // Size of vecors is different. Prevent overflows. Calculate from right to left
    int indexD1 = static_cast<int>(d1.size()) - 1;
    int indexD2 = static_cast<int>(d2.size()) - 1;
    int indexResult = static_cast<int>(result.size()) - 1;

    // Now add each digit in the vector of digits
    for (size_t index{}; index < ResultSize; ++index) {
        const unsigned char sum = carry + (indexD1 >= 0 ? d1[indexD1] : '\0') + (indexD2 >= 0 ? d2[indexD2] : '\0');
        result[indexResult--] = sum % 10;
        carry = sum / 10;
        --indexD1;
        --indexD2;
    }
    return result;
}

// Basically standard approach for calculating Fibonacci Numbers
Digits getFibonacciNumber(size_t index)  {
    Digits f1{ 0 }, f2{ 1 }, f3{ 0 };
    while (index--) { 
        f3 = f2 + f1; 
        f1 = std::move(f2); 
        f2 = std::move(f3); 
    }
    return f2;
}

int main() {
    if (std::ofstream oss("r:\\fibo.txt"); oss) {

        // Calculate Fibonacci number for 1000000
        Digits result = getFibonacciNumber(1000000);

        // Show output. Suppress leading zeroes
        bool showZeros{ false };
        for (const unsigned int i : result) {
            if ((i != 0) || showZeros) {
                oss << i;
                showZeros = true;
            }
        }
        oss << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Resulting in a Fibonacci number with 208980 digits.

Since I used a 0-optimized version, the runtime for the calculation will be really long.

So, happy calculating . . .

I will later create an optimized version.

---

**EDIT**

I tried to optimize as much as I could. But still for the 1'000'000th Fibonacci Number I still need 403s to calculate the 208980 digit result.

Please see the code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

constexpr size_t MaxDigits = 250'000u;

using Big = std::array<unsigned char, MaxDigits>;
std::array< Big, 3> f{};

int main() {

    size_t index = 100000u;

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::array<size_t, 3> sf{};
    std::array<size_t, 3> indexF{ 0,1,2 };

    f[indexF[1]][0] = 1;
    sf[indexF[1]] = 1;
    size_t i{};

    unsigned char carry{};
    while (index--) {

        const size_t indexF0 = indexF[0];
        const size_t indexF1 = indexF[1];
        const size_t indexF2 = indexF[2];

        const size_t sf0 = sf[indexF0];
        const size_t sf1 = sf[indexF1];
        const size_t maxSize = std::max(sf0, sf1);

        for (i = 0; i < maxSize; ++i) {

            const unsigned char f0 = f[indexF0][i];
            const unsigned char f1 = f[indexF1][i];

            const unsigned char sum = carry + f0 + f1;

            (f[indexF2])[i] = sum % 10;
            carry = sum / 10;
        }
        if (carry) {
            f[indexF2][i] = carry--;
            ++sf[indexF2];
        }
        else
            sf[indexF2] = maxSize;

        std::rotate(indexF.begin(), indexF.begin() + 1, indexF.end());
    }

    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
    std::cout << "Time: " << elapsed.count() << " ms\n\nNumber of digits: " << sf[indexF[0]] << "\n\n";

    //for (int k{ static_cast<int>(sf[indexF[0]])-1 }; k >= 0; --k) std::cout << static_cast<int>((f[indexF[0]])[k]);
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering, what else I could do to improve further . . .