# ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and '__int128') win MinGW

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I am trying to compile the following code with MinGW (x86_64-13.1.0-release-win32-seh-msvcrt-rt_v11-rev1):

```
#include <iostream>

void f()
{
    __int128_t val = 1;
    
    std::cout << val;
}
```

and getting the following compiler error:

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and '__int128')
[build]    16 |         std::cout << val;
[build]       |         ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~
[build]       |              |       |
[build]       |              |       __int128
[build]       |              std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and '__int128')
[build]    16 |         std::cout << val;
[build]       |         ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~
[build]       |              |       |
[build]       |              |       __int128
[build]       |              std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
```

Why is it ambiguous?

**EDIT1**

The same error with GCC in online compilers.

**EDIT2**

The same result with the following code:

```
void f1 (uint64_t val) {}
void f1 (int32_t val) {}

void f()
{
    __int128_t val = 1;
    
    f1(val);
}
```

Comment: I guess that ```operator<<``` has no overload for ```__int128``` thus the compiler find a suitable conversion (as a [compilation diagnosis](https://godbolt.org/z/hejq795P1) says) to other numerical types and find several, thus the ambiguity.
You may have to explicitly cast to a supported type but with possible loss of precision.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print \_\_int128 in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114597/how-to-print-int128-in-g)

Answer (score 2):

The error means that there are no overload of `operator<<` exactly for `__int128_t`, which is not mentioned in standard and which is not cross-platform, it is specific to the GCC compiler.

For this reason, the compiler tries to implicitly convert the value to other types like `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, etc. As a result, this conversion causes ambiguity, because there are many types to which it is possible to convert `__int128_t`, and there are multiple operator overloads for those types.

As far as I know, the only way to print `__int128_t` is to write your own operator overload. [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114597/) for another question, where you can find code snippets for creating such an overload. One of the possible variants (copied from the answer in the given link) looks like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const __int128_t& x) {
    if (x == std::numeric_limits<__int128_t>::min()) return o << "-170141183460469231731687303715884105728";
    if (x < 0) return o << "-" << -x;
    if (x < 10) return o << (char)(x + '0');
    return o << x / 10 << (char)(x % 10 + '0');
}
```

But, if in your code you have to use such big numbers, it is better to use cross-platform libraries, not compiler-specific types. For example, you can use a [BigInt](https://faheel.github.io/BigInt/#usage) library for usage of arbitrary-sized integers.

Comment: Is Bigint library fast enough comparing to __int128_t? (I read somewhere some time ago that division can be problematic)

Comment: Of course, it would be a bit slower than using fixed size types, but it is relatively fast

Comment: @RomanLeshchuk [See boost cpp_int](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html).  See it [used here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66541088/computing-the-1-millionth-fibonacci-number/66541479#66541479).

Answer (score 2):

Write your own operator to do the conversion and printing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, __int128_t val)
{
    std::string result;
    bool is_negative = val < 0;
    if (is_negative)
    {
        val *= -1;
    }

    do
    {
        result.push_back((val % 10) + '0');
        val /= 10;
    }
    while (val != 0);

    if (is_negative)
    {
        result.push_back('-');
    }

    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return (os << result);
}

int main()
{
    __int128_t val = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max();
    
    std::cout << (val * 900000);
    return 0;
}
```